# Tag Synonym Request: adobe-flash-player to flash-player

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Or, you know, vice versa...

[adobe-flash-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash-player) should be linked, somehow, with [flash-player](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flash-player). My preference is to include the manufacturer's name in the product, but either way would work

Comment: [flash-player] is the historical tag and the excerpt says it refers to Adobe Flash Player.  So a couple of questions: 1) Are there other Flash players?  2) If there are, do they warrant separate tags (Adobe's vs. others)?  3) If there are other players, would a synonym cause confusion for questions not about Adobe's?

Comment: @fixer the built in flash player for Windows 8, the native flash player on chrome?

Comment: So that answers #1.  Past practice, then, was to lump them all under [flash-player], which suggests that maintaining separate tags will be a lost cause.  So if we have both tags, they should just be synonomized, which answers #2.  Given non-Adobe Flash players, the generic tag should be the primary or the tag will appear incorrect for non-Adobe questions, which addresses #3.  We've gone until now without people having a problem finding the [flash-player] tag because they were looking under Adobe.  But if you think an [adobe-flash-player] tag is warranted, I'll vote for it as a synonym.  :-)